# Produce multiple correlation "heatmaps" with a for loop, for many variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a dataset with 127 variables:

```
cols <- c("Important", paste("var", 1:126, sep = ""))
```

I have a cormat object produced like this:

```
cormat <- round(cor(data), 3)
```

I also have a 27" 1440 monitor (if that's important). And when I produce the heatmap...

```
library(ggcorrplot)
ggcorrplot(cormat, lab = TRUE,
       outline.col = "white", ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_gray)
```

... well, I can't read it because it has too many variables. I've tried different numbers, and more than 30 variables is illegible. So I did:

```
ggcorrplot(transac_shadow_cor[1:30, 1:30], lab = TRUE,
           outline.col = "white", ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_gray)
ggcorrplot(transac_shadow_cor[31:60, 31:60], lab = TRUE,
           outline.col = "white", ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_gray)
```

And so on, producing 5 legible heatmaps. (1:30, 31:60, 61:90, 91:120, 121:127)

**Request:** I want to build a `for loop` that builds these heatmaps but i'm lost on how to subset by 30 for all the variables. Would be **AMAZING** if on top of it, i can have the first variable "important" on every heatmap, because.. it's important, but it's no biggie if i don't.

I'm not attached to `ggcorrplot`, it's just the one i'm using.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a starting point:

```
transac_shadow_cor
Size <- 30
Init <- 0
Iteration <- floor(dim(transac_shadow_cor)[1] / Size) #You have some remaining 
variables 
End <- Size

for (i in 1:Iteration){
  ggcorrplot(transac_shadow_cor[c(Init+1):End, c(Init+1):End], lab = TRUE,
         outline.col = "white", ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_gray)
  Inti <-  Init + Size
  End <- End + Size
}
```

Comment: Very close!, but with your answer I managed to find a solution myself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, cool.
@Orlando Sabogal almost had it. Here is my code based on his proposal:

```
Size <- 30
Init <- 0
Iteration <- floor(dim(transac_shadow_cor)[1] / Size) #You have some remaining 
End <- Size
heatmaps <- c()                   # this strores heatmaps for latter printing

for (i in 1:Iteration) {

  # Store each heatmap
  heatmaps[[i]] <- ggcorrplot(transac_shadow_cor[c(Init+1):End, c(Init+1):End], lab = TRUE,
                              outline.col = "white", ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_gray)

  # now print it
  plot(heatmaps[[i]])
  Init <-  Init + Size           # he had a typo here
  End <- End + Size
}
```

Now for the tricky part. Printing it with the "Important" variable on each plot

```
Size <- 30
Init <- 0
Iteration <- floor(dim(cormat)[1] / Size) #You have some remaining 
End <- Size
heatmaps <- c()                           # this strores heatmaps for latter printing
range <- c(1, seq(from = 2, to = End))    # the range of variables to appear on the heatmap

for (i in 1:Iteration) {

  # Store each heatmap
  heatmaps[[i]] <- ggcorrplot(cormat[range, range], lab = TRUE,
                              outline.col = "white", ggtheme = ggplot2::theme_gray)

  # now print it
  plot(heatmaps[[i]])

  # move the chains of the loop
  Init <-  Init + Size                         # he had a typo here
  End <- End + Size
  range <- c(1, seq(from = Init+1, to = End))  # increase range
}
```

And it works! Ha! It looked like a scary thing but it's not that bad after all. Thanks @Orlando Sabogal, wouldn't have made it without your idea